# How to automatically update datagrid from IObservable<T>

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I use this library `https://github.com/step-up-labs/firebase-database-dotnet` to retrieve items from firebase, then display it to datagrid in realtime.

But I got stuck when displaying it, based on the link above to get realtime streaming, I need to use this code:

```
var firebase = new FirebaseClient("https://dinosaur-facts.firebaseio.com/");
var observable = firebase
  .Child("dinosaurs")
  .AsObservable<Dinosaur>()
  .Subscribe(d => Console.WriteLine(d.Key));
```

I try this code but nothing displayed on the gridview:

```
var observable = firebase
    .Child("news/item")
    .AsObservable<News>();

disposable = observable.Subscribe();

dataGrid.ItemsSource = observable.AsObservableCollection();
```

I also try this without any luck:

```
private ObservableCollection<News> _myItems = new ObservableCollection<News>();
private IEnumerable<News> MyNews { get { return _myItems; } }

private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var observable= firebase
        .Child("news/item")
        .AsObservable<News>();

    _myItems = observable.AsObservableCollection();

    disposable = observable.Subscribe();

    dataGrid.ItemsSource = MyNews;
}
```

Comment: Put a break point on `dataGrid.ItemsSource = MyNews;` and check that you actually get the items back. Also does your `DataGrid` has `AutoGenerateColumns` set to true? And please use MvvM with WPF. It's not WinForms where everything is a hand balled.

Comment: @XAMlMAX It's just simple program to display a thing, and I know nothing about MVVM, beside I learn MVP before

Comment: My assumption was that this is part of a bigger solution. That's why I insisted on MvvM. Anyway glad to hear your problem is solved. Take care

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is observable callbacks, including modifying `ObservableCollection` returned by `AsObservableCollection`, run on thread pool thread by default. But you cannot modify `ObservableCollection` on non-UI thread, so there is exception which is swallowed. So instead, do it like this:

```
var observable = firebase
      .Child("news/item")
      .AsObservable<News>();            
dataGrid.ItemsSource = observable
    .ObserveOnDispatcher() // < key point
    .AsObservableCollection();
```

Don't forget to install nuget package `System.Reactive.Windows.Threading` and add `using System.Reactive.Linq;` to access `ObserveOnDispatcher` extension method.

Also no need to call `observable.Subscribe();`, unless of course you need it for other things. `AsObservableCollection` already subscribes.

Comment: Hi, I got this error IObservable does not contain a definition for 'ObserveOnDispatcher'

Comment: @SIRS add "using System.Reactive.Linq;" If doesn't help - install nuget package "System.Reactive.Windows.Threading"

Comment: Does this also work in the opposite direction, where when you change a value on the DataGrid, the database value is also updated?

Answer (score 0):

@Evk but there`s a problem either with ObserveOnDispatcher() or with datagrid

I have described this problem in this post:

[ObserveOnDispatcher duplicates records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61240052/observeondispatcher-duplicates-records)