# ObserveOnDispatcher duplicates records

Tags: c#, wpf, firebase, datagrid

I'm using WPF with Firebase to work with data.

When I use the following code to reveal all data to Datagrid:

```
void ShowProducts()
{
    var products = client
         .Child("freshfish")
         .AsObservable<Products>();

    ProductsDataGrid.ItemsSource = products
        .ObserveOnDispatcher()
        .AsObservableCollection();
}
```

It works well, but after a few minutes it duplicates all the records once again.

Here's how it looks:

[image: Normal state]

[image: After 1-2 minutes]

Any ideas?

Comment: The reason is ridiculous: this project was made on .NetFramework platform, I've taken it to .NetCore and everything is great. I noticed, downloading the firebasedatabase.net package on NetFramework, many other dependencies are included, unlike NetCore. Maybe that's the point...

Comment: What versions of .NetCore and System.Reactive are you using? I'm attempting to port my .NET Framework app to .NET 5 (core) and for reasons unknown, `ObserveOnDispatcher` is not available